# How to store data automatically after some seconds in laravel using ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel-6

I have created the article post section in my project. In post article i want to store data automatically save as drft in my articles table.
Here I have put the blade file with form and ajax code. This ajax code is not working means nothing is happening in background. When I enter title no data is stored and when I open console and check it only works string running. plz see this link also  https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Hkup.jpg

```
<form action="{{ route('articles.store') }}" method="POST" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
  @csrf

  <div class="card shadow">
   <div class="card-body pt-3">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div >
            <input id="title" type="text" placeholder="Enter title here" class="form-control form--control{{ $errors->has('title') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="title" value="{{ old('title') }}">
            @if ($errors->has('title'))
            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
              <strong>{{ $errors->first('title') }}</strong>
            </span>
            @endif
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div>
           <textarea name="description" id="mytextarea"  class="form-control textarea {{ $errors->has('description') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" placeholder="Description">{{old('description')}}</textarea>

           @if ($errors->has('description'))
           <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
            <strong>{{ $errors->first('description') }}</strong>
          </span>
          @endif
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">

      <div class="card">
       <div class="card-body">


         <div class="form-group">
          <label for="category_id">Choose category:</label>
          <select name="category_id" id="category_id" class="form-control @error('category_id') is-invalid @enderror"  value="{{ old('category_id') }}"   >
            <option value="0">Select Category</option>
            @foreach($category as $category)
            <option value="{{$category->id}}">{{$category->name}}</option>
            @endforeach
          </select>
          @error('category_id')
          <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
          </span>
          @enderror

        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="subcategory_id">Sub category:</label>
          <select id="subcategory_id" name="subcategory_id" class="form-control">

          </select>

        </div> 



        <div class="form-group">
          <small>Publish Date</small>

          <div>
            <input id="datepicker" type="text" class=" py-2 form-control{{ $errors->has('show_date') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="show_date" value="@if(old('show_date')=="") {{date('Y-m-d')}} @else {{ old('show_date') }} @endif">
            @if ($errors->has('show_date'))
            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
              <strong>{{ $errors->first('show_date') }}</strong>
            </span>
            @endif
          </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
          <div>
            <small>Featured image</small>
            <input id="image"  name="image"  type="file" class="form-control {{ $errors->has('image') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" value="{{ old('image') }}">
            @if ($errors->has('image'))
            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
              <strong>{{ $errors->first('image') }}</strong>
            </span>
            @endif
          </div>
        </div>  



      </div>
    </div><!-- End Right Col -->


    <div class="card">
     <div class="card-body">
      <strong>Tag :</strong>
      <section id='outside-of-the-box'>

        <aside class='rightSide'>
          <input name='tags' class='tagify--outside form-control' value='' placeholder='write some tags'>
          <small>Tag's with comma separator</small>
        </aside>
      </section>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
<a href="{{ route('articles.index') }}" class="btn btn-outline-secondary font-weight-normal mr-2">Cancel</a>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary font-weight-normal px-3" name="publish" value="Publish">
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-secondary font-weight-normal mx-2" name="save" value="Save as Draft">
</div>        

</div>

</div><!-- End Row -->
</div>
</form>
```

This is the scripting ajax code...

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>  
 $(document).ready(function(){  
      function autoSave()  
      {  
           var title = $('#title').val();  
           var description = $('#mytextarea').val();  
           // var category_id = $('#category_id').val();  
           if(title != '' && description != '')  
           {  
                $.ajax({  
                     url:"{{url('articles')}}",  
                     method:"POST",  
                     data:{title:title, description:description},  
                     dataType:"text",  
                     success:function(data)  
                     {  
                          // if(data != '')  
                          // {  
                          //      $('#category_id').val(data);  
                          // }  
                          $('#autoSave').text("Post save as draft");  
                          setInterval(function(){  
                               $('#autoSave').text('');  
                          }, 3000);  
                     },

                });  
           }            
      }  
      setInterval(function(){   
           autoSave();   
           }, 3000);  
 });  
 </script>
```

This is my resource route

```
This is my resource route
Route::resource('articles','ArticleController');

datatabel column fields are

title
description
category_id
show_date
slug
draft
```

Comment: Wild guess - there are only 3 lines of JS in what you have shown, and the last one includes what looks like a syntax error - an extra random `datepicker`.  That probably means no other JS on the page works or runs.  If that's not it, maybe you can clarify, eg 1) `Here I have put the blade file with form and ajax code` - there is no AJAX code here; 2) `when I open console and check it only works string running` - what does this mean?

Comment: @Don'tPanic oh sorry my mistake...i forgot to paste ajax...my bad.. when I run the code the console running like this? means when script runs..

Comment: In laravel you have to use token while doing ajax call for post method.

Comment: @AkhtarMunir can you please fix this code..?

Comment: @NeerajTangariya see answer

Comment: Your screenshot shows the word "works" logged to the console 17 times ... but the AJAX code you've shared here does not log anything to the console? Where is your real code? Have you checked the network tab of your devtools? Are the POSTs actually sent, with the data you expect, and if so what was the server response?  Is your `url('articles')` really the right URL for updates?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend doing some changes in your ajax part, just copy my code.

```
$.ajax({  
       method:"POST", 
       url:"{{ route('articles.store') }}",  //Here you are using just `articles` so which route ? You have to write something like mine. Because it's a resource route.
       data:{title:title, description:description,_token:@json(csrf_token())}, //You also need to pass token here as well, like I have done for you
       success:function(data)  
       {  
         console.log(data);  
       },
       error: function(data){
         console.log(data);
       }
    });
```

And from controller first return just a simple hello message to see, like `return "Hello";` when you receive a message then the rest you can carry on.

One important thing I want to mention that you are using resource routes and controller, so your route names would be like this.

1. articles.index
2. articles.store
3. articles.create etc...

If you want to see all routes of your resource route, run this command in `cmd` within your project directory

```
php artisan route:list --path=articles
```

Comment: `just copy my code` - why? What is different in your code, and how does it fix the problem in OP's code? This might be the answer, but your answer would be much higher quality if you explain what you did and why.  Copy-pasting is not learning, for either OP or all the future SO visitors that will come here.

Comment: @Don'tPanic if you see the coment on the answer you will know, why I have written this phrase `just copy my code`, and few points I have pointed out as well.

Comment: Sorry, coment on Question *